# Reference Error Javascript

Tags: javascript

The error is

```
ReferenceError: fighters1_txt is not defined
```

I have variables defined in a self executing function. These are not global. There is a nested function that is referencing the variables below. For some reason I am getting a reference error. I already tried

```
console.log(fighter1_txt);
```

and other debugging methods and the error still remains. I know that this error occurs if the variable is simply not declared, but in this case the variable is declared.

```
//DEFINE YOUR dom pieces; Multiple ways to define/access HTML tags
var fighter1_txt = document.querySelector("#fighter1text").querySelector("p");
var fighter2_txt = document.querySelector("#fighter2_txt").querySelector("p");
var round_txt = document.querySelector("h4");
var button = document.getElementById("fight_btn");
```

If you need I can show the entire function to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is not in fact declared. `fighter1_txt` and `fighters1_txt` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're having an extra **s** in your reference.

```
fighters1_txt // should be fighter1_txt
```

Then it would work.